# Extracting information from 2 separate lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, extract

I want to extract certain information from a large file using python.
I have 3 input files.
The first input file (input_file) is the data file, which is a 3-column tab-separated file that looks like this:

```
engineer-n imposition-n 2.82169386609e-05
motor-n imposition-n 0.000102011705117
creature-n imposition-n 0.000121321951973
bomb-n imposition-n 0.000680302090112
sedation-n oppression-n 0.000397074586994
roadblock-n oppression-n 5.96190620847e-05
liability-n oppression-n 0.012845281978
currency-n oppression-n 0.000793989880202
```

The second input file (colA_file) is a 1-column list, which looks like this:

```
bomb-n
sedation-n
roadblock-n
surrender-n
```

The third input file (colB_file) is also a 1-column list (idential to colA_file with different information), which looks like this:

```
adjective-n
homeless-n
imposition-n
oppression-n
```

I want to extract information from the input file that is found in both colA and colB.
With the example data that I have provided, this would mean filtering all of the information except for the following lines:

```
bomb-n imposition-n 0.000680302090112
sedation-n oppression-n 0.000397074586994
roadblock-n oppression-n 5.96190620847e-05
```

I have written the following code in Python to solve this task:

```
def test_fnc(input_file, colA_file, colB_file, output_file):
    nounA = []
    with open(colA_file, "rb") as opened_colA:
        for aLine in opened_colA:
            nounA.append(aLine.strip())
            #print nounA

    nounB = []
    with open(colB_file, "rb") as opened_colB:
        for bLine in opened_colB:
            nounB.append(bLine.strip())
            #print nounB

    with open(output_file, "wb") as outfile:
        with open(input_file, "rb") as opened_input:
            for cLine in opened_input:
                splitted_cLine = cLine.split()
                #print splitted_cLine
                if splitted_cLine[0] in nounA and splitted_cLine[1] in nounB:
                    outstring = "\t".join(splitted_cLine)
                    outfile.write(outstring + "\n")

test_fnc(input_file, colA_file, colB_file, output_file)
```

However, it only outputs 1-line, as if it is not iterating over the list inputs provided.
It also seems that my lists are being appended upon each other, starting with one item and incrementing itself with each appended item.
Thus, I have also tried to reference the lists as follows:

```
    for bLine in opened_colB:
        nounB = bLine
```

with the same result as above.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the contents of `nounA` and `nounB`? You may need to `strip` newline characters etc.

Comment: I just tried, but that does not solve the problem. I will update the code to include the cleaning of newline characters though.

Comment: shouldn't `for cLine in opened_cosine` be replaced by `for cLine in opened_input`?

Comment: @owwoow14 just use `.strip()` instead of `.rstrip('\n')` and that will fix it - the lines look like e.g. `b'sedation-n\r\n'`, so you need to remove more than just the `'\n'`.

Comment: @yoopoo yes you are right. I tried to anonymize the code and forgot to change that part. I updated the question to revise it.

Comment: @owwoow14 can you show what is written to your output file? I tried your code and it worked...

Comment: However, your code is lack of efficiency.

Because you use `list` to search a `string`, it takes O(n) time complexity. You could use `dict` or `set` instead.
And it is easy to find the `Intersection of Sets` by `set`

Comment: The code output the first line that it finds, my intuition that it was not iterating properly over the entire input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `pandas` or `numpy` if you don't mind the dependency. With a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) you can then perform [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html#pandas.DataFrame.isin) checks on its columns. Otherwise I'd recommend using sets since regex should be much slower. Something like this:

```python
with open(colA_file, "rb") as file_h:
    noun_a = set(line.strip() for line in file_h)

with open(colB_file, "rb") as file_h:
    noun_b = set(line.strip() for line in file_h)

with open(output_file, "wb") as outfile:
    with open(input_file, "rb") as opened_input:
        for line in opened_input:
            split_line = line.split()
            if split_line[0] in noun_a and split_line[1] in noun_b:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

nounA=[]
with open('col1.txt', "rb") as opened_colA:
    for aLine in opened_colA:
        nounA.append(aLine.strip())

patterns = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in nounA]
col1 = re.compile('|'.join(patterns))
nounB=[]
with open('col2.txt', "rb") as opened_colA:
    for aLine in opened_colA:
        nounB.append(aLine.strip())

patterns = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in nounB]
col2 = re.compile('|'.join(patterns))

with open('test1.txt', "rb") as opened_colA:
    for aLine in opened_colA:
        if col1.search(aLine):
            if col2.search(aLine):
                print aLine

# just write aline to your output file.
```

**Explanation:** first I am taking the all the words in `colA` and making a regular expression; similarly with `col2`. Now with that regular expression I am searching the input file and printing the result

`'\b'` is word boundary. If you're searching for a word `'cat'` but it may find `'catch'`, `'\b'` is useful so to find only word `'cat'`.